# What's the difference between そうですね, そうですか, そうです

Tags: expressions, particle-か, particle-ね

How are the following different:

- そうです (thats right)
- そうですか (i see;  is that so)
- そうですね (thats right)

also what's the difference between いいです and いいですね?

reference or sentence in context much appreciated  especially example/s of where one uses "thats right" in english and then its translated to japanese which of そうですね or そうです are used any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer, but these are called LRs ("listener responses") in linguistics, and ALL Japanese learners require a lot of practice before being able to deploy them naturally. I don't say this to be discouraging, just that it's something that seems like it should be so easy, but it takes time!

Comment: Also, いいそうで and いいそうですね are not common expressions. Are you thinking  of いいです and いいですね?

Comment: いいです and いいですね is what i meant sorry i edit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

そうです is a way of saying 'yes, that is certain.'
For example, a discussion using the word might go like this:

> 4+3=7 ですか？ (Is 4+3=7?)
>
> > はい、そうです。(Yes, that is certain.)

On the other hand, そうですか is, as the definition you provided, can be both I see; or is that so?

If you used it as 'I see':

> 椅子に引っかかって腕を折りました。(I tripped on a chair and broke my arm.)
>
> > そうですか。。。 (I see...)

If you used it as 'Is that so?':

> 4+3=8です。 (4+3 is 8.)
>
> > そうですか？ (Is that so?)

そうですね is a more intimate version of そうです、 and usually used when you are talking to a person of higher rank. It can also be used to start a sentence like 'um,'

Used like 'yes, I agree':

> 社長：　ロッククライミングは危ないと思います。(Boss: I think Rockclimbing is dangerous)
>
> > 社員：　そうですね。(Worker: Yes, I agree.)

Used like 'um':

> あなたはどう思いますか？ (What do you think?)
>
> > そうですね、良いと思います。(Um, I think it is good.)

いいです and いいですね is the same thing as before, the one with the ね　is more intimate version, and usually used when you are talking to a person of higher rank.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ありがとうございます！タイプミスでした。。。（汗）